# MySQLi Transaction Server gone away

Tags: php, mysqli

I use the following code to insert some orders in the DB with a mysqli transaction. Sometime it works without any problems and sometime it just throws an error after 1 minute saying: "Mysqli Server gone away". When I trigger the same thing just after the error it just works. 
The php file is trigger via jquery post.

```
function InsertOrder($children){
  global $mysqli;
   foreach($children as $child){
     InsertOrder();
   }
}
require('../../sys/connect.php');
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); 
$error = false;

foreach($_POST){
   InsertOrder($children);
}
if(!$error)
{
    $mysqli->commit();
    die("done");
} else 
{
    $mysqli->rollback();
    die(getLanguageKey("label_mysqli_rollback",array($error)));
}
```

It's just a light version of my code, but that's it.
If I remove "$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);" it works all the time.

It also works in other recursive functions I use.

You can log in at [ur.ready2order.at](http://ur.ready2order.at) with the demo account button. Then you can call: 
http://ur.ready2order.at/views/order.dev.php?t_id=155

This site uses the mentions script. Sometime mysqli server gone away...sometime not.
Clicking the white button puts the product to order list and blue part of button opens the sidedishes and comment function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. As I rebuild my code from using mysql to mysqli, I forgot to rewrite a small function. This caused the error because it was still looking for mysql().

Sorry guys and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation about it: [MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html)

Try to change your [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) or increase speed of your script.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if this solved my problem. One time it just works like a charm and then it ends in the "server gone away" message. the script itself runs in just about a second. So I just don't get it. :(

Comment: *an error after 1 minute*, *runs in just about a second* be more clear.